# Mootools: how to show tips manually

Tags: mootools, tooltip

I would like to show a tooltip by calling it from code.  Something like:

```
tips.fireEvent('show', el);
```

or

```
label.fireEvent('mouseover');
```

The tips are already set and stored on domready and work perfectly on mouseover.  MooTools 1.4.5.

Comment: uh huh, and how do you expect us to try and help when you have posted no code, nor given us any idea as to what you mean.

Comment: what tips? the ones from mootools-more?

Comment: Yes, MooTools More Tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked was creating a new tip:

```
var tip_title = el.retrieve('tip:title');
var tip_text = el.retrieve('tip:text');
var tips = new Tips(el, {fixed: true, offset: {x: 0, y: size.y}});
var tip = tips.toElement();
tip.getFirst('div.tip').set('html', '<b>' + tip_title + '</b><br />' + tip_text);
var pos = el.getPosition();
var size = el.getSize();
tip.setStyles({left: pos.x, top: pos.y + size.y});
tips.show(el);
```

Then, just added a little extra code to detach the additional tip on mouseover.